# Habilitar campo text al dar click en select option en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

**Hola soy nuevo en este foro, les comento que estoy implementando un sistema de registro de mascotas, que al momento de dar click en varios debe de desplegarse un input text, he tratado de hacerlo con onclick y no funciona, les pido sugerencias.**

---

```
<div class="form-group col-12 col-md-4">
                  <label for="raza-mascota">Raza</label>
                  <select
                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-placement="bottom"
                    title="Este campo es obligatorio"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="razaMascotaRegistra"
                    onchange="addCleseRazaRegistra ()"

                  >
                    <option value="" >-Raza-</option>
                    <option value="2" >Schnauzer</option>
                    <option value="3" >Cruzado</option>
                    <option value="4" >Otros</option>
                  </select>
                </div>  
<div class="form-row mb-3 justify-content-center d-none" id="razaOtroMascotaRegistra">
                <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-8 ">                      
                  <input                           
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"                        
                    placeholder="* Especifica la raza de tu mascota"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
function remCleseRazaRegistra() { 
var razaOtroMascotaRegistra = document.getElementById("razaOtroMascotaRegistra");
razaOtroMascotaRegistra.classList.remove("d-none");
};
```

Comment: que es lo que no funciona exactamente, lo digo por que veo el onchange que usas en el select pero la funcion addCleseRazaRegistra no la has colocado y no veo donde se utiliza el remCleseRazaRegistra....

Comment: Te explico, al momento de enviar el formulario valida campos y nos envía mensajes de error uno de esos mensaje es si no selecciona una raza nos pide seleccionar raza, entonces al momento de seleccionar la raza debe de desaparecer dicho errot, ejemplo doy click en cruzado debe de desaparecer el mensaje que le pide seleccionar raza, ahora, el problema surge que cuando doy en otros debe de desaparecer el mensaje y aparecerme un cuadro txt para escribir la raza..

Comment: y este error donde lo colocan? un span, label, p

Comment: a ok en el input aparece el mensaje no?

Comment: <div
                    class="alert alert-danger d-none"
                    id="mensajeErrorRazaReg"
                  >
                    Debe de seleccionar una raza
                  </div>  pero esto ya lo tengo

Comment: podrías añadir el código con el que validas?

Comment: Debe de aparecer el input cuando el usuario le de click al valor de **otros**?

Comment: el código esta allí que es el segundo bloque y la función, mejor dicho la función busca el id = razaOtroMascotaRegistra, ahora como lo acciono en option value="4", que al momento del dar click en otro me debe de aparecer un cuatro text para ingresar la raza otro.

Comment: <div class="form-row mb-3 justify-content-center d-none" id="razaOtroMascotaRegistra">
                    <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-8 ">                      
                      <input                           
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"                        
                        placeholder="* Especifica la raza de tu mascota"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div> ----- esto debe de aparecer

Comment: Ya te deje una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

La explicación esta en el código, cualquier duda hazla saber, también agregue desde el principio un style al div que sería `style="display: none"` para que este oculto desde que carga la página.

```js
function addCleseRazaRegistra(){

  let valor = document.getElementById('razaMascotaRegistra').value; //obtenemos el valor del select
  
  console.log(valor);

  if(valor == 4){ // si es igual a 4 que significa "otro"
  
    document.getElementById('razaOtroMascotaRegistra').style.display = 'block'; //mostramos el id que contiene el input
  
  }else{
  
  document.getElementById('razaOtroMascotaRegistra').style.display = 'none';//si no lo volvemos a ocultar
  
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-12 col-md-4">
                  <label for="raza-mascota">Raza</label>
   <select  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Este campo es obligatorio" class="form-control"  id="razaMascotaRegistra" onchange="addCleseRazaRegistra()"  >
                    <option value="" >-Raza-</option>
                    <option value="2" >Schnauzer</option>
                    <option value="3" >Cruzado</option>
                    <option value="4" >Otros</option>
                  </select>
                </div>  
<div class="form-row mb-3 justify-content-center d-none" id="razaOtroMascotaRegistra" style="display: none">
                <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-8 ">                      
 <input  type="text" class="form-control"placeholder="* Especifica la raza de tu mascota" />
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Hola, muchísimas gracias, me funciono de maravilla... un fuerte abrazo desde Perú

Comment: De nada, buen día compañero! :)