# Seleccionar razas

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estamos implementando un sistema de registro de mascotas, queremos seleccionar las razas, ejemplo al dar clic en perros me debe aparecer un combo con las respectivas rasas y al dar clic en gatos debe de aparecer con las razas de los gatos, esperamos su ayuda, gracias.

```
                 <label for="raza-mascota">Especie</label>
                  <select
                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-placement="bottom"
                    title="Este campo es obligatorio"
                    class="form-control"
                  >
                    <option value="">-Especie-</option>
                    <option value="1" >Perro</option>
                    <option value="2" >Gato</option>
                  </select> 
                  <label for="raza-mascota">Raza</label>
                  <select
                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-placement="bottom"
                    title="Este campo es obligatorio"
                    class="form-control" 
                  >
                    <option value="" >-Raza-</option>
                    <option value="2" >Schnauzer</option>
                    <option value="3" >Cruzado</option>
                    <option value="4" >Otros</option>
                  </select>
```

Comment: Podrías generar dos arreglos uno con la raza de gatos y otro con la de perros y dependiendo que seleccione pues haces el vaciado del array en el select correspondiente.

Answer (score 4):

La explicación está en el código, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
//creo dos arreglos con las razas que voy a utilizar

let r_perros = ['Beagle','Labrador','Bulldog','Schnauzer'];
let r_gatos = ['Gato persa','Gato siamés','Burmés','Gato himalayo'];

//agrego la funcion change() para obtener el valor cada que el usuraio cambie la opción
$('#especie').change(function(){

//tomo el valor
  let val = $(this).val();
  
  //Guardo en una variable el selector de raza por comodidad
 let raza_select = $('#raza');
 
 
 // si es perro
 if(val == 1){
  
  //vaciamos lo que haya porque al hacer el cambio a gato 
  //se va a quedar el arreglo y así sucesivamente
     raza_select.empty();
     
     //agregamos el selecciona porque igual se borra
     raza_select.append(`<option value="">Selecciona</option>`);
     
     //utilizamos forEach para recorrer nuestro arreglo de perros
    r_perros.forEach(function(perro, index){
    //usamos append y con template strings nos ahorramos el concatenado con '+'
    raza_select.append(`<option value="${index}">${perro}</option>`);
    
    });
    //cambiamos el atributo disabled por false para poder seleccionr la raza
    raza_select.prop('disabled', false);
    
    $('#content_otro').remove();
    
  }else if( val == 2){
    
    //el mismo procedimiento que en el case de perro
    raza_select.empty();
     raza_select.append(`<option value="">Selecciona</option>`);
    
   r_gatos.forEach(function(gato, index){
    
    raza_select.append(`<option value="${index}">${gato}</option>`);
    raza_select.prop('disabled', false);
    });
    
    $('#content_otro').remove();
  
  }else if(val == 3){
    
    // si selecciona 'Selecciona' Pues volvemos a deshabilitar el de raza hasata que elija otro+
    raza_select.append(`<option value="">Selecciona</option>`);
    raza_select.prop('disabled', true);
    
    raza_select.after(`<div id="content_otro">Especifica: <input type="text" id="otro" name="otro">
    </div>`);
    
    
    
    }else{
    
    raza_select.append(`<option value="">Selecciona</option>`);
    raza_select.prop('disabled', true);
    
    $('#content_otro').remove();
    
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Selecciona la especie: <select id="especie">
  <option value="">Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">Perro</option>
  <option value="2">Gato</option>
  <option value="3">otro</option>
  
</select>


Selecicona la raza: <select id="raza" disabled>
  <option value="">Selecciona</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Muchas, gracias, pero me gustaría aprovechar el momento para preguntarte algo, tanto perros como gatos debe de haber una opción otros, entonces al darle clic en otros debe de aparecer un input de tipo text para especificar la raza.

Comment: Esa pregunta ya te la había contestado aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287522/habilitar-campo-text-al-dar-click-en-select-option-en-javascript

Comment: Cómo lo estás implementando?, no es copiar y pegar, si haces eso no va a funcionar tienes que adaptarlo.

Comment: Te explico, el código que me enviaste, ahora ultimo para seleccionar la especie y luego la raza funciona.. el problema es ahora que deja de funcionar, el campo otros..

Comment: Gracias solucionado...

Comment: Ya modifiqué mi respuesta, si te fue de ayuda marca la respuesta como aceptada, en la paloma gris pasará a verde, así otro compañero que tenga el mismo problema o relacionado sabrá cuál fue la solución.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando un operador ternario y un array anidado te ahorras repetir código.

```js
const animales = [
  ['Beagle', 'Labrador', 'Bulldog', 'Schnauzer'],
  ['Gato persa', 'Gato siamés', 'Burmés', 'Gato himalayo']
];

$('#especie').change(function() {

  $("#raza").prop('disabled', false)
    .html("<option value=''>Selecciona</option>");

  (+$(this).val()) ?
  animales[+$(this).val() - 1].forEach(e => {
      $("#raza").append(`<option>${e}</option>`)
    }):
    $("#raza").prop('disabled', true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Selecciona la especie:
<select id="especie">
  <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">Perro</option>
  <option value="2">Gato</option>

</select>


Selecicona la raza:
<select id="raza" disabled>
  <option value="">Selecciona</option>

</select>
```

Ademas, al array animales puedes agregarle más arrays de razas que va a seguir funcionando sin necesidad de cambiar el js, siempre que agregues la opción en el select de animales, obviamente. Idealmente el select de animales y el de razas debería salir del mismo set de datos.

Comment: Muchas, gracias, pero me gustaría aprovechar el momento para preguntarte algo, tanto perros como gatos debe de haber una opción otros, entonces al darle clic en otros debe de aparecer un input de tipo text para especificar la raza